# The difference of two sigma algebras

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am having trouble proving that the difference of two sigma algebras is a not a sigma algebra.
My counterexample is that if we choose two sigma algebras
$$F_1= \{ \emptyset,\Omega, A, A^c\} $$  and
$$F_2= \{ \emptyset,\Omega \} $$   then  we make  the difference
$$F_1 -F_2$$ this is equal to  $$F_1= \{ \emptyset, A, A^c\} $$
And this is not a sigma algebra.
My question is, that if this is correct or Omega also belongs

Comment: $\ F_1-F_2=\big\{A,A^c\big\}\ $. So $\ \Omega\not\in F_1-F_2\ $, but $\ \emptyset\not\in F_1-F_2\ $ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by lonza leggiera, $ F_1-F_2=\big\{A,A^c\big\}$ hence if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A\neq \Omega$, $\Omega$ does not belong to  $F_1-F_2$.